Best Practices for RBAC/ABAC in REST API with mandatory and optional attributes
I am currently working on a REST API where we've traditionally indicated which fields are mandatory and which are optional in the response or DTO. This has been straightforward as each endpoint had a fixed set of mandatory and optional fields.
Now, we're introducing attribute or role-based access control (RBAC) or attribute access control (ABAC) on certain endpoints, and this approach no longer works. E.g. Each role can have a different set of mandatory and optional fields, making it challenging to maintain clear and consistent responses and DTOs.
For example:
We have 3 attributes in the response a,b,c
a and c are mandatory and b is optional
Role A is allow to see attribute a, b but not c.
Role B allow to see attribute c, b but not a.
Should be all attributes be optional?
Additionally, in this example absent/null/optional is semantically the same in response.
My question is: What are the best practices for handling access control in REST APIs where mandatory and optional attributes can vary by access rules?
How can I maintain clear and user-friendly API documentation+response+DTO classes under these conditions?
Any best practices or examples would be beneficial.
Even if more than one solution is certainly conceivable.
Examples
Java
public class MyDto
{
   @NotNull
   String a;

  
   Optional<String> b;
   
   //String c or Optional<String> c
}

Open Api
MyDto:
  required:
    - a
    #- c
  properties:
    a:
      type: string
    b:
      type: string
    c:
      type: string

To start the discussion.
The first thoughts were the following 4 solutions
a) One Endpoint with different payloads/DTOs for every role
b) For every role a own endpoint with a dedicated payload/DTO
c) Every role specific attribute is a Optional
d) Every role has an own optional root element which included then the specific attributed
Further ideas?

What is your current way to indicate whether DTO attribute is optional or not? It's hard to say what should be changed without seeing the "as-is" example

Not sure what you mean, because "absent/null/optional" is described.
I can add a Java example as well or open api
